# Unable to retrieve crawling information

Tags: python

[image: image of output]

As you can see from the result screen in the picture, the class name is correct and there seems to be no mistake. But I'm not getting any results.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

response = urlopen("https://www.naver.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
for anchor in soup.select('span .realtime_item'):
  print(anchor)
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9sJ7.png)

Translate. The site can no longer be crawled this way.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

response = urlopen("https://www.naver.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
for anchor in soup.select('.realtime_item'):
  print(anchor)
  print("\n\n")
```

Comment: Unfortunally, not work in my IDE (goorm IDE what web editer)

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting any data because SPAN doesn't have anything like **realtime_item**. Try to print soup and find if the value is there or not and then do select

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
    
response = urlopen("https://www.naver.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Comment: Now that I've finished loading the pages, the price of the <li> tag I want has been dynamically recalled, which is impossible in this way.